# Trying to find a reason why `(n * 2) / 4 == (n / 4) * 2` works

Tags: algebra-precalculus, programming

Earlier today I was programming an example in Lua that takes in the diameter of a circle and outputs the area.

```
circle_darea = function(diameter)
   local radius = diameter / 2
   return self.pi * radius * radius
end;
```

A first iteration would probably produce the above code. But being me, I wanted to use the diameter directly instead of the local variable. So I came up with the following code.

```
circle_darea = function(diameter)
   return self.pi * (diameter/2) * (diameter/2)
end;
```

However, this repeats the diameter twice and I pondered if there was another way, not that this isn't a correct solution. The function explicitly converted the diameter or 'inlined' it. I produced the following code.

```
circle_darea = function(diameter)
   return self.pi * ((diameter * 2)/4)
end;
```

This struck me as very odd because it introduces this math rule: `(n * 2) / 4 == (n / 4) * 2`. Indeed it does seem to be law. So then I did a little research to re-familiarize myself with the basic rules of algebra and the closest I saw was `Associative property of multiplication` but with a side note of `(and division)`.

One thing I have not tried is replacing the 2's with a unique variable and the 4's with a unique variable to see if it is reoccurring in other forms. Does anyone have an explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: $\frac{2n}{4} = \frac{2}{1} * \frac{n}{4} $ is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes, that is a non-programmers way of writing it :)

Comment: well, remember that the product of fractions is defined as  $\frac{a}{b} * \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ac}{bd}$  so replacing the values, you can see why it's true. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Note that the second function  does *not* calculate the area. The correct expression would be  "return self.pi * ((diameter * diameter)/4)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide means: multiply by the reciprocal.  So
$$
\frac{n \cdot 2}{4} = n \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}
$$
and
$$
\frac{n}{4}\cdot 2 = n \cdot \frac{1}{4}\cdot 2
$$
These are equal according to the **commutative property** of multiplication.

Comment: Note, I used $\cdot$ for multiply (since this is a mathematics group) and not $*$ as they do in computer programs.

Comment: How Donlans Donlans put it, I can see the transition of the numbers. I am not sure how you got `(n*2)/4` into `(n/4)*2`. Wouldn't the reciprocal be `4/(2 * n)`?

Comment: I actually see the construction of the right hand side into the left hand side on the first example. It took converting the fraction into a decimal. I want to thank my highschool math teachers for distributing a gracious amount of 'its just how you do it'